# What will be the number of integer points lying within the circle?

Tags: geometry

What will be the number of integer points lying within the circle $(x-10)^2+(y-10)^2=200$ and also in the first quadrant?Neglect points on the circle.

Suggestions please.

Integer point means both coordinates are integers.

Comment: Points on the circle to be neglected or not?

Comment: edited...@Aniket

Comment: First sketch a diagram. Then try counting: points the number of points along each horizontal line with $y$ ordinate an integer: $(n,0)$, then $(n,1)$, etc.

Comment: @SimonS That's the way I think I would do it. I really wish there was some cool way to cut up the circle into polygons and find the areas and use [Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem) in some cool way but I don't really see how ...

Comment: @SimonS that's a good traditional method i'd say.But really i wanted to extend it to ellipses and other conic sections too...me looking for something "more" i'd say. (I guess i should make another thread for that though)

Comment: I can't say I know any neat rules off the top of my head. So I would start here and see if you can deduce anything useful. There are clearly some symmetries.

Comment: This can be done easily with a computer program, which would also make it easy to extend to other conic sections.

Comment: This is not an exact answer, but the number of integer points inside a circle of radius $r>0$ is of the order of the area of the circle. The estimation of the error term is a classical problem in number theory known as the [Gauss circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm might be worth reading.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html would help.